# Creating and assigning a Task in microsoft To-Do From a sharePoint

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Hbs.png)

Hi, I am trying to create a Flow in PowerAutomate that runs every time an item is created in a SharePoint. Once the item is created the flow must create a task in Microsoft To-do and assign it to the person specified. I created the flow and used the Add a to-do(v3) action, but I see that it doesn't have a field to assign the task to a specific person. My question is: is it possible? or is there a work around to complete this task??

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not currently available. You’d think and hope it would be, but it’s not.

The limitation isn’t on the PowerAutomate/LogicApps side, it’s actually on the Microsoft Graph API side. It doesn’t support assigning the task to a specific person.

There is no work around using the API’s, what’s available via the Graph API is all there is.

Your only other solution would be to use something like **PowerAutomate Desktop** but that’s a lot of work for something so small. You need to tack it on to the end of your current flow but you’ll need a license for PAD, you’ll need a PC that runs PAD and you’ll need to create your PAD flow.

My suggestion would be to send an email to someone after the to-do item is created so they can assign it. That’s about the best you can do for now I’d say.

Answer (score 0):

As opposed to the answer of Skin, there is a possibility to get this to work.

If you make a PowerApps app where a user uploads the document to SharePoint, the flow that is shared with the user will run using their OAUTH2 connection, i.e. they create a connection to their own To-Do list and this is automatically taken care of.

Using your automated task, the answer is no indeed, Graph API hasn't opened up their associates route yet sadly.